# Run Windows (for Steam in-home streaming) and Ubuntu (for my other applications) on my server simultaniously

Tags: server, virtualbox, games, virtualization, steam

I use a server now for [Plex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plex_(software)) and some other applications I'd rather run in Linux. But I'd also like to use my server for Steam in-home streaming and a lot of my games only run on Windows. Can I run Ubuntu and Windows simultaneously, or is there some other workaround for this, because I've already read that running games in [Virtualbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu and Windows simultaneously requires virtualizing your machine, with [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), [kvm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), or some other solution. This is a non-trivial process.

But, games frequently want all computing power available, so if the performance detracts from your game play, you may wish to consider shifting all your Linux apps to another, lesser PC which uses less power. Add samba to it for file sharing, and control it from the Windows machine with a [remote control client app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software). Hardware's cheap, these days...

Comment: I could build a second server, but I don't want it to cost to much for power and with 2 servers that's getting pretty hard.  Is there a way to make server more efficient by software?

Comment: VirtualBox, kvm, and Hyper-V are the leading lights of virtualization. Folks are trying to get them faster all the time. Trying.